# How to set android-minSdkVersion correctly in Phonegap CLI

Tags: cordova, phonegap-cli

I am using Phonegap CLI 6.0.3 to generate android app. I want to set minSdkVersion = 19.

according to [how-do-i-specify-the-android-api-level-in-phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384723/how-do-i-specify-the-android-api-level-in-phonegap) and [how-can-i-specify-the-minimum-sdk-in-phonegap-it-is-ignoring-android-minsdkvers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135185/how-can-i-specify-the-minimum-sdk-in-phonegap-it-is-ignoring-android-minsdkvers), i should modify the sdk number in

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

However, when i try to install the app in a android 4.3 phone (sdk 18), it still work. how can i forbid people intall my app in andorid phone sdk = 18 or below?

Answer (score 0):

You should change it manually in

```
  yourproject/config.xml

    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19"/>
```

The next time you build, Cordova should set it on the Android Manifest.

If that doesn't work, you can change it in

```
  yourproject/platforms/Android/AndroidManifest.xml

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="XX" />
```

But keep in mind that this file is built automatically and isn't really meant to be changed, so it can be overriden or some other unexpected behaviour.